# Dynamic Query Issue

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

Variable : `path_start_date=14-MAY-21,17-MAY-21,06-APR-12`

Query :

```
select greatest(''||REPLACE(''''||&path_start_date||'''',',',''',''')||'')
from dual;
```

Expected Output =  `17-MAY-21`

Can anyone suggest what's wrong with the above query.

Answer (score 0):

Split input string into rows, and fetch the `MAX` value:

```
SQL> with temp (val) as
  2    (select '14-MAY-21,17-MAY-21,06-APR-12' from dual)
  3  select
  4  max(to_date(regexp_substr(val, '[^,]+', 1, level), 'dd-mon-yy',
  5              'nls_date_language = english'
  6             )
  7     ) max_datum
  8  from temp
  9  connect by level <= regexp_count(val, ',') + 1
 10  /

MAX_DATUM
---------
17-MAY-21

SQL>
```

Comment: Could you please provide solution in dynamic query or help me found the error in my query??

Comment: Dynamic what? Instead of a string in line #2, use e.g. `select :par_string from dual` instead.